# HTTP vs TCP for online games

Tags: http, tcp

I am wondering about the difference between HTTP and TCP data transfer protocols for online games.
I have heard many people using TCP or UDP to transfer data between client and server for online games. 
But can you use http at all? I know http is mostly used for web browsing, but if I could set up web server and let my game applications use GET and POST methods, I can still send data back and forth right? Is it that this way of communicating is too slow or unnecessary?

And just one thing about TCP transmission protocols, if I were to write some gaming application using TCP, is it that the data are usually transferred using something called "sockets" (like Socket classes in Java)? What about UDP?

Thanks very much!
Appreciate any answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP is an additional layer on top of TCP that defines what a request looks like, what a response looks like, and how the connection is closed or maintained across requests. You can either use it or not use it, depending on what you actually need to transport. If your game consists of a series of requests that each get a reply, HTTP might make sense. If it's more like unsolicited messages in each direction, making HTTP work is like putting a square peg in a round hole.

Most platforms provide a socket interface that allows you to work with either TCP or UDP depending on the protocol specified when the socket is allocated. Some higher-level APIs look completely different for different protocols.

Comment: I see.. Thanks so much!